# Microsoft.Extensions.Logging - LogError is not logging exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using the simple `ASP.NET` provided logger that I get via dependency injection: `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<T>`. In practice the dynamic type is `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger<T>`.

When catching exceptions I'm trying to log them using: `_logger.LogError(exception, "message")`, however only the message is printed.

```
namespace App
{
    public class App : IApp
    {
        private readonly ILogger<App> _logger;

        public PomParser(ILogger<App> logger)
            => _logger = logger;

        public void DoStuff()
        {
            try
            {
                DoStuffUnsafe();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex,"Failed to do stuff");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How I configure the logging:

```
var host = new HostBuilder().ConfigureLogging(ConfigureLogging)...
...
await host.RunAsync();
```

```
        private static void ConfigureLogging(HostBuilderContext hostContext, ILoggingBuilder configLogging)
        {
            configLogging.ClearProviders();
            configLogging.AddConfiguration(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            configLogging.AddFile(
                options =>
                {
                    hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("FileLoggingOptions")
                        .Bind(options);
                }
            );
            configLogging.AddConsoleLogger();
        }
```

appsettings:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "FileLoggingOptions": {
    "FileName": "app-",
    "LogDirectory": "logs",
    "FileSizeLimit": 10485760,
    "Extension": "log"
  }
}
```

Comment: @Fildor added config

Comment: `configLogging.AddFile()` – What is that? There’s no built-in file logger. So if you don’t see exceptions, then it’s *that* logger that apparently doesn’t support logging them.

Comment: @poke you're right, its from an external package: https://github.com/andrewlock/NetEscapades.Extensions.Logging but I don't see it logged to console either, and that's a built in logger

Comment: that logger does not log to file

Comment: You called `configLogging.ClearProviders();` so of course all the built-in loggers are gone unless you add them explicitly again. So you don’t see console logs because there is no console logger.

Comment: That rolling file logger you linked [does indeed write out the exception](https://github.com/andrewlock/NetEscapades.Extensions.Logging/blob/master/src/NetEscapades.Extensions.Logging.RollingFile/Internal/BatchingLogger.cs#L64-L67) so it should work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the default `MessageFormatter`: https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/LoggerExtensions.cs

```
        private static string MessageFormatter(FormattedLogValues state, Exception error)
        {
            return state.ToString();
        }
```

It simply ignores the exception ... I implemented a custom Console logger:

```
public class ConsoleLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
        => new ConsoleLogger(categoryName);

    private class ConsoleLogger : ILogger
    {
        private readonly string _categoryName;

        public ConsoleLogger(string categoryName)
            => _categoryName = categoryName;

        public void Log<TState>(
            LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception,
            Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter
        )
        {
            if (!IsEnabled(logLevel))
            {
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(
                $"{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [{logLevel}] {_categoryName}: {state}{(exception != null ? "\n" : string.Empty)}{exception}"
            );
        }

        public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
            => true;

        public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
            => null;
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
public static Task Main(string[] args)
    => WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(...)
        .ConfigureServices(...)
        .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, loggingBuilder) => loggingBuilder.AddProvider(new ConsoleLoggerProvider()))
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build()
        .RunAsyncSafe();
```

Comment: So if you bypass the extension method.. and use something like this... 
      this.theLogger.Log(LogLevel.Error, ex, "My Extra" + ex.Message);        ... will that also work?

Comment: @granadaCoder yes, but that would require always remembering to add the `+ ex.Message` and also won't print the stack trace

Comment: Doesn't IsEnabled returning true mean that the check on IsEnabled is redundant?

Comment: Indeed, but its part of the interface. You could also implement your own logic that allows the logger to be disabled on some condition.

Answer (score 30):

If your logger isn't logging the exception it could also be because you accidentally got the order of the passed arguments wrong:

```
_logger.LogError("An error occurred", e)     // WRONG: Exception will not be logged
```

The correct order is providing the *exception object* always as the ***first*** argument:

```
_logger.LogError(e, "An error occurred")     // OK: Will log the exception
```

---

> References:
>
> https://blog.rsuter.com/logging-with-ilogger-recommendations-and-best-practices/#always-pass-exception-as-first-parameter

Comment: argh, I traced it to our own implementation.  My bad.  I deleted my comment.